# Where git keeps initial project version?

Tags: git

Let's imagine I have an a Git repository and now I'm staying on the commit `X`.
After i will have finished to write some new code I'll be in the commit X but with some diffs (uncommited changes):

```
commit X -> coding process -> (commit X + diffs)
```

Now I call `git diff` command and see comparing of initial and current versions. Therefore Git has an access to project initial version of current commit.

My question is - where in `.git` folder Git keeps an initial version of project to create that diffs? And how Git keeps that initial version?

Comment: In its `.git` folder. Concerning the format how it stores that, that's non-trivial.

Comment: If you’re really interested, then read the git book. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects Don’t make us read it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I did not get your question but what you are looking for is not simply the output of

```
git diff
```

Which describes your changes after the last commit?

If instead you want to compare the behaviour of your code before and after the changes (i.e. run some tests) you can use

```
git stash
```

To basically go back to your last commit state and

```
git stash pop
```

To revert it back to your uncommited changes.